# count number of words in a txt file

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos

I'm a beginner in coding especially on assembly language. So I got a problem on the code that I make. The task is to design an assembly code, and test a program that prompts the user to enter the name of a text file, checks if the file exists, and if it does, counts the number of words in the file and displays the result on the screen. If the file does not exist, an error message is displayed and the user is prompted to enter the filename again.

So far I already manage to make a code that read a txt file from a file but don't have idea on how to count the words contained on the file. My code is something like this, im using DOSBox to compile and assemble the code:

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
            prompt          db 10,13, "Enter the file name: $"
            filename        db 100,102 dup("$")
            filehandle      dw ?
            open_msg        db 10,13, "File successfully opened! $"
            open_error_msg  db 10,13,"File cannot be opened! $"
            count_msg db 10, 13, 'The number of words in the file: $'
            word1 db 1 
            
.code
start:
    ;Initiate
    mov ax,seg open_msg
    mov ds,ax

; Display Prompt message ===
retry:
    mov dx,offset prompt
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    ; Enter Filename ===
    mov dx,offset filename
    mov ah,10
    int 21h
    mov bl,filename[1]
    cmp bl,8
    ja retry
    jmp store

store:
    mov [bx+filename+2],0

;Open the file
open:
    mov ah, 3Dh
    mov dx, offset [filename+2] 
    mov al,2
    int 21h
    jc retry

    ;if file successfully opened, save the filehandle
    mov [filehandle],ax
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,offset open_msg; display file opened succesfully
    int 21h
    
    jmp count_loop
    

error_when_open:
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,offset open_error_msg
    int 21h

; PART for Counts the number of words in the file 

; continue the PART for Counts the number of words in the file here
count_words:
    mov cx, 0
    mov si, 0

count_loop:
    mov ah, 3fh
    mov bx, filehandle
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, offset word1
    int 21h
    cmp ax, 1
    je increment
    cmp ax, 0
    je end_count
    mov al, word1
    cmp al, ' '
    je increment
    jmp count_loop

increment:
    inc cx
    jmp count_loop

end_count:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset count_msg
    int 21h
    mov dx, cx
    add dx, 48
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp close



close:
    mov ah,3eh
    mov dx,filehandle
    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h


end start
```

I hope someone can give me idea on how to solve this problem, provide answers that can complete the code and the task. Thanks for your time.

Comment: First you need to define what a word is. As it is, you seem to be counting spaces. That should about work for what is intended, do you have a problem with that? Note: your printing only does single digits so better not have more than 9 spaces :)

Comment: Counting words from a text file can be done in most any language: you need an algorithm that meets your definition of word(s) to scan the contents.  You don't have to think in assembly to do this, so work out an algorithm in a language you know, and then take that algorithm to assembly language.

Comment: yes I have problem with it since I'm still a newbie.

Comment: Yeah well the question is **what** problem do you have because you did not say.

Comment: How to define word?. I don't really familiar with that. By any chance, Do you have example?

Comment: That is a parameter choice for your task. Are words separated by exactly one space? May there be punctuation marks? Multiple ones? End of line? Do numbers count as words?

Comment: I see. What changes do I need to do?. Should I delete the count_words, count_loop?

Comment: You do not understand. You can make no changes **before you decide** what the definition of "word" is. Also you still have not said what the problem of the current version is.

Comment: I'm apologies for the misunderstanding. The problem of the current version is that it didn't count the number of words contained in the file entered..the result is like this. Enter the file name : hi.txt. although the file contained 5 words..it just display "Number of words in the file: 1". It didn't calculate at all.

Comment: Your problem is you do `mov cx, 1` while reading the character and that obviously overwrites your counter. You need to save and restore that. Or you could simply use another free register such as `si`.

Comment: so I need to change mov cx,1 to mov si,1 only? or change the whole set of cx to si?

Comment: Your testing of the read result and the counting is totally wrong. You increment as long as you successfully read a byte and you keep the count in a register that is being overwritten at every iteration.

Comment: @MuuN Change the whole set of `cx` to `si`.